# Changing ID value to all rows in database + rename all folders

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 1000 listings / rows in a table.. + 1000 folders in root (named as per ID, for example 1, 2, 3 etc..)

I have a button called "**change id's**"

When clicked, it get's the last id (1001) and changes all 1000 id's to start from 1001..

I have this working by this code:

```
UPDATE vehicles v 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(id) maxid FROM vehicles) x 
   SET v.id = v.id + x.maxid
```

What I don't understand how to do, is also do the SAME to the FOLDERS for each listing.. as the images for each listing are "linked/tied" to the old ID in this case...

Can someone help me please how can I also change the folders names exactly as the ID's are changing now?

Comment: you can change folder and file names with [`rename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)